# As a lab assistant, how many hours per week am I expected to be helping out?

Tags: undergraduate, teaching-assistant, working-time

I am in my third year of computer engineering studies, and was offered a position as lab assistant in the electronics lab. I am oriented towards software, so I'm not exactly interested in the subject itself, but to my understanding, being a lab assistant is quite a good thing for the CV, plus it's good to be a familiar face to a professor or two, and I like the work, so I'd generally like to continue.

What makes me skeptical is the fact that I am in the lab for two hours on Monday evening (I miss the first hour due to an overlapping class), three hours on Thursday evening, and six hours on Friday from 3pm up to 9 o'clock, which brings the total time up to 14 hours. While I can probably cope with that, I was also asked to grade some reports (is it even legal for undergrads to grade undergrads?), a subject I want to discuss on another question.

At any rate, I have felt a big impact on my independent pursuits since I started, namely some days I'm at the campus all day so I don't feel like I'm doing much, and I really can't stand not doing stuff.

**The question** comes down to this: As an undergrad lab assistant, how much time am I expected to devote to the lab, and how much work am I expected to do at home? How serious a commitment did I make?

Comment: 2 + 3 + 6 = 14?

Answer (score 2):

In graduate school, this would be dictated by your GRA (graduate research assistant) contract, which would specify a minimum number of hours you would be expected to work on research each week.

As an undergraduate research assistant, if you're getting paid OR if you're receiving credit for your work, I would expect this to be dictated by your contract or a syllabus (respectively). If neither of those conditions are true, then this is a matter to take up with the professor you work for. Consider telling them that you would like to cut back on your responsibilities to pursue other interests, but know that they might counter with telling you that you're no longer needed. Negotiate carefully and respectfully.

For the record, 14 hours doesn't seem too extreme, even for an undergraduate research assistant. And if you're being paid, whether or not you can be asked to grade depends largely on the terms of your contract, though it doesn't seem unreasonable. In any event: negotiate respectfully with your boss, just as you would do in any other job.

Comment: There's no contract, graduate students get less than 100 euros per month (not much money coming into the university) and we don't get a dime, and I'm not getting credits either. I *am* receiving a document signed by the professor that I did assist at his lab though. As for the 14 hours, on their own they are ok, but I've got another 32 hours of lessons, a project deadline every now and then, and also some presentations and events as a campus representative for a company, which is nearly weekly preparation, and I'd really love to pursue some of my own projects, so it gets bad in the end.

Comment: @user3079666: So you're in Europe?  That's important information - I'd add that contextual knowledge to your initial question, as you may be able to get some help that's tailored to your country (I'm in the U.S.).

Comment: @user3079666: But in any event - based on your comment, I think you already know that you're going to need to make a choice here.  You've got a fixed number of hours in the week, a fixed number of responsibilities academically, and then you need to leave time for eating/sleeping/showering/the rest.  So it boils down to what's more important for you - the time spent working in the lab?  Or the time to pursue your own projects?  Answer that question, and then negotiate with your professor based on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your  institution's regulations.

Explanation:
The workload for a TA in a lab depends on the resources and constraints. By resources I mean the lab instructors and other lab TAs allocated for the same subject. I'll list some of the other dependant factors below

- Whether the subject or its syllabus is new
- Complexity and density of the lab subject subject syllabus
- Number of students per batch
- Amount of work imposed by the department for the subject
- Professor who handles that subject.

Comment: I doubt there are any regulations in the entire country for this kind of stuff, it's all dependent on the professors. The professor who runs this lab told be to work as much as I want and as long as it doesn't interfere with my other duties, but that is variant as project deadlines change and other events come up.

Comment: @user3079666, did you discuss with students of other professors? You should be able to get a statistical average.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31145)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, the labs each professor runs have a varying number of teams, and often different duration, so I don't think I can ask anyone other than the professor in charge of that lab. If I ask him, it may seem like I am trying to avoid the work without coming out straight.

Comment: @jakebeal: I've added the details